# ANT build error : Incorrect Classpath

Tags: android, ant, classpath

I'm using ANT to do a build of an android project. Unfortunately, i'm getting an error:
 [javac] incorrect classpath:.......

and it lists the class path that is in the eclipse project. we're using the EJC compiler because otherwise we have some stuff break in generics.

i thought for some reason it must be picking up the .classpath file info, so i deleted the libraries listed in there, and they still show up in the error.

so i'm wondering, where's it getting this classpath from? the directories i'm seeing aren't specified anywhere in the build.xml file.

also, what exactly does this error mean? i've googled the hell out of it, and it doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: Getting a bit closer, it was pulling them in via this: <condition property="extensible.classpath"                  value="${tested.project.absolute.dir}/bin/classes" else=".">

still very confused though, it onmly has the bin\classes, \src and \gen folders now but it's still saying incorrect classpath. what does this error mean? there is a space in the directories, does that matter?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. we have brackets in our folder name, e.g. c:[whatever] and that causes it to fail. so it's an ANT bug.